# TCL TK Progress Bar for large file transfer: too much time

Tags: copy, tcl, tk-toolkit, large-files, chunks

I suggested this solution to a colleague that needed to implement a progress bar for file copy. Here's the code, basically a modified version of another example I found:

```
proc CopyMore {in out chunk bytes {error {}}} {
    global total done transferredBytes totbytes
    incr total $bytes
    incr transferredBytes $bytes
    if {([string length $error] != 0) || [eof $in]} {
        set perc [expr int($transferredBytes*100/$totbytes)]
        updprog $perc
        puts "$transferredBytes $totbytes"
        puts $total
        set done $total
        close $in
        close $out
    } else {
        set perc [expr int($transferredBytes*100/$totbytes)]
        updprog $perc
        puts "$transferredBytes $totbytes"
        fcopy $in $out -command [list CopyMore $in $out $chunk] -size $chunk
    }
}

proc Copy {in out chunk} {
    global total done
    set total 0
    set start [clock seconds]
    fcopy $in $out -command [list CopyMore $in $out $chunk] -size $chunk
    vwait done
    set end [clock seconds]
    return [expr $end-$start]
}

proc CopyFile {source dest} {
    set chunk [expr 1024*1024*18]
    set in [open $source]
    set out [open $dest w]
    fconfigure $in -translation binary
    fconfigure $out -translation binary
    retur[Copy $in $out $chunk]
}
```

The `CopyFile` function is called for every file I need to copy. The `fconfigure $in -translation binary` seems needed here, because I'm handling binary files (already tried to remove this instruction and just a few bytes were actually copied).

I supposed that this copy was designed for large files, but I noticed that the copy process is extremely slower compared to the previous solution (without chunks, progressbar, etc). Here some numbers to copy about 1.3 GB:

| Method | Time (secs) |
| --- | --- |
| Previous solution | 9 |
| Chunk 256K | 178 |
| Chunk 1M | 143 |
| Chunk 18M | 127 |
| Chunk 100M | 122 |
| Chunk 300M | 121 |

So it seems that increasing the chunk size slightly improves the performance but all these results are very far from the previous solution.

I can't explain such a difference. Do you guys have the same issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**UPDATE!** I added the following instructions in the `CopyFile` function:

```
fconfigure $in -buffersize  1000000
fconfigure $out -buffersize  1000000
```

and now this new copy tecnhique is about 20% slower than the previous one.

Do you guys have any suggestion to reduce more such time difference?

Comment: One of the first suggestions to speed up a Tcl script is to brace your expressions.

Comment: With large chunk sizes, that shouldn't make _too_ much difference. Should be done, but unlikely to be transformative given that we're talking about I/O as what should be the dominant factor.

Comment: Which is exactly why I posted my suggestion as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried to brace the expressions and I didn't notice much speed improvements, as you already said.